# Diagrams R/GrViz: Is there a way to arrange the labels in an even way along the arrows/edges? Plus, how can I curve the covariance arrow/edge?

Tags: graphviz

I'm actually quite happy with the graphics so far, but the labels along the graphics and the non-curved double arrow don't satisfy me yet.

1. Is there a way to distribute the labels evenly along the labels. e.g. that the labels along TEST 1 are all exactly vertically above each other? Or can I move the labels at TEST 2 horizontally apart? The same applies to the values that are close to the arrows themselves (such as 0.49**, -0.35 or 0.22*). Exact coordinates cannot be given for the labels, can they?
2. How do I get the covariance arrow/edge curved?

```
grViz("
digraph SEM {

graph [layout = neato,
       overlap = true,
       outputorder = edgesfirst]

node [shape = rectangle]

a [pos = '-5,1!', label = 'parcel 1']
b [pos = '-5,0!', label = 'parcel 2']
c [pos = '-5,-1!', label = 'parcel 3']
d [pos = '-5,-2!', label = 'parcel 4']

e [pos = ' 2,-5!', label = 'parcel 5']
f [pos = ' 3,-5!', label = 'parcel 6']
g [pos = ' 4,-5!', label = 'parcel 7']
h [pos = ' 5,-5!', label = 'parcel 8']

i [pos = ' -4.25,-5!', label = 'Item 1']
j [pos = ' -3,-5!', label = 'Item 2']
k [pos = ' -2,-5!', label = 'Item 3']
l [pos = ' -1,-5!', label = 'Item 4']
m [pos = ' 0,-5!', label = 'Item 5']

n [pos = '-3,-0.5!', label = 'TEST1', shape = ellipse]
o [pos = '3.5,-3!', label = 'TEST', shape = ellipse]
p [pos = '-2,-3!', label = 'TEST2', shape = ellipse]
q [pos = '5,-0.5!', label = 'TEST']
r [pos = '-1,2!', label = 'TEST']
s [pos = '2,2!', label = 'TEST'] 

n->a [label='0.71', headport = 'e']
n->b [label='0.72', headport = 'e']
n->c [label='0.65', headport = 'e']
n->d [label='0.64', headport = 'e']

o->e [label = '0.79', headport = 'n']
o->f [label = '0.79', headport = 'n']
o->g [label = '0.79', headport = 'n']
o->h [label = '0.78', headport = 'n']

p->i [label = '0.35',  headport = 'n']
p->j [label = '0.48',  headport = 'n']
p->k [label = '0.81',  headport = 'n']
p->l [label = '0.64',  headport = 'n']
p->m [label = '0.72',  headport = 'n']

o->q [label = '0.55**' fontname = 'times-bold']
p->q [label = '0.05']
n->q [label = '-0.04']
r->q [label = '0.00']
s->q [label = '0.15']

r->o [label = '-0.01']
n->o [label = '0.49**'  fontname = 'times-bold']
s->o [label = '0.22*'  fontname = 'times-bold']

n->p [label = '-0.35*'  fontname = 'times-bold']
r->p [label = '-0.03']
s->p [label = '0.15']

r->n [label = '0.33**'  fontname = 'times-bold']
s->n [label = '0.19']

r->s [label = '0.00']

i->j [dir = both]
p->o [dir = both, label = '-0.20' ]

}
")
```

[image]

Comment: which is the "covariance edge"? and does bent mean curved or something else?

Comment: Since in the grViz documentation the arrow connections are called "Edges", I have named them in the same way here. The covariance edge is the one with the double arrow. Bent means curved, yes!

Answer (score 0):

you can try to coerce labels to move by adding spaces and/or newlines to the text (https://www.graphviz.org/docs/attr-types/escString/) or you can try html-like text (https://graphviz.org/docs/attr-types/lblString/).  you can also use **headlabel** and/or **taillabel** (https://www.graphviz.org/docs/attrs/headlabel/)

**neato** (and the other engines) only support one line style per graph (see https://www.graphviz.org/docs/attrs/splines/) (**neato** defaults to **splines=false**), so no direct way to get a curved edge.  You can use other techniques to draw attention to specific edges by using color or style attributes (https://graphviz.org/docs/attr-types/style/) - see attached.

```
digraph SEM {

graph [layout = neato,
       overlap = true,
       outputorder = edgesfirst]

node [shape = rectangle]

a [pos = "-5,1!", label = "parcel 1"]
b [pos = "-5,0!", label = "parcel 2"]
c [pos = "-5,-1!", label = "parcel 3"]
d [pos = "-5,-2!", label = "parcel 4"]

e [pos = " 2,-5!", label = "parcel 5"]
f [pos = " 3,-5!", label = "parcel 6"]
g [pos = " 4,-5!", label = "parcel 7"]
h [pos = " 5,-5!", label = "parcel 8"]

i [pos = " -4.25,-5!", label = "Item 1"]
j [pos = " -3,-5!", label = "Item 2"]
k [pos = " -2,-5!", label = "Item 3"]
l [pos = " -1,-5!", label = "Item 4"]
m [pos = " 0,-5!", label = "Item 5"]

n [pos = "-3,-0.5!", label = "TEST1", shape = ellipse]
o [pos = "3.5,-3!", label = "TEST", shape = ellipse]
p [pos = "-2,-3!", label = "TEST2", shape = ellipse]
q [pos = "5,-0.5!", label = "TEST"]
r [pos = "-1,2!", label = "TEST"]
s [pos = "2,2!", label = "TEST"] 

n->a [label="0.71", headport = "e"]
n->b [label="0.72", headport = "e"]
n->c [label="0.65", headport = "e"]
n->d [label="0.64", headport = "e"]

o->e [label = "0.79", headport = "n"]
o->f [label = "0.79", headport = "n"]
o->g [label = "0.79", headport = "n"]
o->h [label = "0.78", headport = "n"]

p->i [headlabel = "0.35\n",  headport = "n"]
p->j [headlabel = "0.48\n ",  headport = "n"]
p->k [headlabel = <0.81&nbsp;<BR/><BR/>>,  headport = "n"]
p->l [headlabel = "0.64\n       ",  headport = "n"]
p->m [headlabel = "0.72\n ",  headport = "n"]

o->q [label = "0.55**" fontname = "times-bold"]
p->q [label = "0.05"]
n->q [label = "-0.04"]
r->q [label = "0.00"]
s->q [label = "0.15    "]

r->o [label = "-0.01"]
n->o [label = "0.49**\n\n"  fontname = "times-bold"]
s->o [label = "0.22*"  fontname = "times-bold"]

n->p [label = "-0.35*"  fontname = "times-bold"]
r->p [label = "-0.03"]
s->p [label = "0.15"]

r->n [label = "0.33**"  fontname = "times-bold"]
s->n [label = "0.19"]

r->s [label = "0.00"]

i->j [dir = both color="red:blue"]
//p->o [dir = both, label = "-0.20" ]
p->o [label = "-0.20" color=red]
o->p [label = "" color=green]

}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Helped me already a lot! : )